# Flutter devices Unable to locate a development device; please run 'flutter doctor' on Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

I have created a new flutter's project; I can locate the device on Android studio but not on Visual Studio Code, and when I run flutter doctor on Command Line and this is answer that I have: *flutter devices Unable to locate a development device; please run 'flutter doctor' for information about installing additional components*.
Any help please!

Comment: So, when you run `flutter doctor` in turn it says run `flutter doctor`?

Comment: whats the output you get when you run adb devices in cmd

Comment: Yes! it is what it says

Comment: What is the output of `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: [√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.9.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.371], locale en-US)
[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    X ANDROID_HOME = C:\android\sdk;C:\android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\android\sdk\build-tools
      but Android SDK not found at this location.
[√] Android Studio (version 3.0)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.27.1)
[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

Comment: I can see the device connected when I run an _Android project_, but not with _flutter project._

Comment: Can you run Flutter doctor using the `Flutter: Run Flutter Doctor` command in VS Code (not from the terminal) and post the output?

Answer (score 1):

According to **guediriabdou**

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22649#issuecomment-450020266

```
flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk
```

then you have torun this command

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

after that accept all the licenses after that try

```
flutter doctor
```

Comment: This issue is occuring due to I have sdk on different location. Thanks this works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: how to solve Unable to locate a development device flutter issue ?]

Download SDK platform android API 29 then solve this problem